# Installation / Uninstallation logger for Android

Tags: android

I am looking for an Android application that can log all installations and uninstallations of applications. E.g. the log could look like: `timestamp, application name, install/uninstall`. If possible, free and work with Android 4.4.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the "History" apps I found on the Play Store actually write to a log file, but you should be able to be accomplish this with [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.appfactory&hl=en).

You create a profile so it triggers on "new package", a profile on "package removed", and one when a package is updated.

[image]

Then create actions to write to the log file.

[image]

I am by no means an expert with Tasker. But just playing with it, it looks like it could be accomplished.

Comment: Beat me to it! I second your recommendation (+1).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest [App Install History](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=johndoeapps.site.com.google.sites.android.appinstallhistory&hl=en) it shows the following information as mentioned below

- installed Date of an Application
- Application updated Date
- uninstalled histories

> Requires Android
>   1.6 and up

*Required Permission*

```
Version 1.1.1 can access:
Photos/Media/Files
modify or delete the contents of your USB storage
test access to protected storage
Other
full network access
view network connections
```

A screenshot for your reference

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Click image for larger variant</sup>

Comment: Does it create a log file, or at least can export to one?

Comment: @Izzy I think the application itself might be creating a log file,and the option is provided for the user to keep (Maximum Number of Histories) ,and unfortunately there is no export option here :(

Comment: You might wish to include that information with your answer directly ;) Also: Taking a look at the Playstore comments, it seems this app is no longer working correctly. The comments do not make clear whether that might be due to newer Android versions. Have you tested the app yourself? If so, it might be a good idea to point out which Android version you've used, and whether the test was "recent".